# Beginners python program

Tags: python, loops, integer, addition

Decided to help out with doing a lab for my buddy, first time ever doing this so please don't make fun of my code lol. I have to get a number "num" of how many numbers to add to array, then a total number. Then from that I want to add user defined numbers from the size of the array. Then if any of those numbers adds up to the total then print them out, else print sorry. Can't understand why it doesn't work :(

EXTRA EDIT: Problem is, my script does not show the numbers that add up to the total value, only the print('sorry')

edit: I learned prior to this java and C, couldn't figure out the foor loops or how variable types are instantiated.

```
num = int(input('Please enter the amount of numbers you wish to use: '))
total = int(input('Please the total wild card number: '))
hasValue = int(0)
ar = []
i = int(0)
j = int(0)
k = int(0)
l = int(0)
m = int(0)


while (i < num):
    j = i + 1
    inNum = input('Please enter number %d:' %j)
    ar.append(inNum)
    i = i + 1

while (k < num):
    while(l < num):
        if ((ar[k]+ar[l])==total):
            print(ar[k] +' , '+ ar[l])
            hasValue = hasValue + 1
        l = l +1
    k = k + 1
if (hasValue == 0):
    print('sorry, there no such pair of values')
```

Comment: In Python, you can set variables equal to an integer just by doing "j = 0". Python automatically knows that it's an integer. Same with floats: "j = 0.223", and strings: j = "hello"

Comment: Also, i don't clearly understand your problem, could you please rephrase it

Comment: Also, there is no point of the variable 'j'. You are never using it

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do for-loops in python:

```
for x in range(10):
    # code for the for loop goes here
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    // code for the for loop goes here
}
```

... in C++

(Notice how there is no initializing the variable 'x'. When you do a for loop, python automatically initializes it.

Here is what I think you wish to do:

```
def main():
    num = int(input("Enter the amount of numbers: "))
    total = int(input("Enter the total: "))
    array = []
    counter, elem = 0, 0
    for user_numbers in range(num):
        array.append(int(input("Please enter number: ")))
    for each_element in array:
        counter += each_element
        elem += 1
        if counter == total:
            print(array[:elem])
            break
    if counter != total:
        print("sorry...")

main()
```

Comment: Instead of `eval` you could just pass the inputs to `int`. If you want to also support floats then `try: int(x); except ValueError: float(x)`.

Comment: It opens up security holes in your code because _any input is treated as valid Python code and executed_. Ok, this is a toy program on your friend's computer, and you don't care. Well, it's still un-Pythonic, because all you're trying to do is convert to a numeric type. `eval` is not what you mean.

Comment: @Ol'Reliable and what if one of the inputs is `__import__('os').system('rm -rf')`? That would end really badly.

Comment: @Ol'Reliable Just replace `eval()` with `int()` and stop this code security evangelical preaching

Answer (score 1):

As I got it, your current script is looking for two **consequent** numbers where sum equal to `total`, but should search for **any pair in array**, right? So if we have

```
ar = [1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
total = 5
```

program should display `2, 3` pair. But it will not find `1+3` for `total=4`.

Here are some general advices:

1. There is error in `print` invocation, where pair is printed (string should go first in str+int concatenation). Use format

   `print('%d, %d'.format(ar[k], ar[k])`

   or print result as tuple

   `print(ar[k], ar[l])`
2. Use `for k in range(num)` instead of `while`
3. `hasValue` is better to be boolean value

Well, here is my solution (python2.7)

```
num = int(input("Array size: "))
sum = int(input("Search for: "))
a = []
found = False

# Fill array
for i in range(num):
    a.append(int(input("Enter number #{}: ".format(i+1))))

# More effective algorithm - does not check same numbers twice
for i in range(num):
    for j in range(i+1, num):
        if a[i] + a[j] == sum:
            print "{}, {}".format(a[i], a[j])
            found = True

if not found:
    print "Sorry..."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (k < num):
    while(l < num):
        if ((ar[k]+ar[l])==total):
            print(ar[k] +' , '+ ar[l])
            hasValue = hasValue + 1
        l = l +1
    k = k + 1
```

Apart from the fact that the loops are not "pythonic", you need to initialize l = 0 within the k loop.

```
while (k < num):
    l = 0
    while(l < num):
        if ((ar[k]+ar[l])==total):
            print(ar[k] +' , '+ ar[l])
            hasValue = hasValue + 1
        l = l +1
    k = k + 1
```

or slightly more python way:

```
for num1 in ar:
    for num2 in ar:
        if num1+num2==total:
            print(num1 +' , '+ num2) # not sure about this syntax. I am a python beginner myself!
            hasValue = hasValue + 1
```